# initial value problem have infinity many solutions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to show that if there is two solution of IVP( initial value problem) then it has infinite number of solution?

Answer (score 0):

If $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions that are different at $t_1$, then you can follow backwards the initial value problem with $y(t_1)=y_3$ from any point $y_3$ in the segment $[y_1(t_1),y_2(t_1)]$. As this new solution is bounded by the first two solutions, it can be continued until it meets one of the bounding trajectories, from there continue using those. Thus a new different solution for $y(t_0)=y_0$.